# Bottom navigation bar issue in android kotolin

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I have a bottom navigation menu in my app and i have customised it to give it a stylish look and everything looks alright in xml preview but when i run it on emulater or install it n any device a strange color shows up. but that color is not anywhere included in my project.

Have a look and help me.

Xml code

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <layout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
       xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
       xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

        <data>

          <variable
            name="vm"
            type="com.example.myapplication.ui.main2.HomeViewModel" />
       </data>

       <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/background_color2"
        tools:context=".ui.main2.HomeActivity">

        <androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
            android:id="@+id/frame"
            android:name="androidx.navigation.fragment.NavHostFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:navGraph="@navigation/home_nav_graph" />


        <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
            android:id="@+id/navView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/_42sdp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/_15sdp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/_20sdp"
            android:background="@drawable/nav_background"
            android:forceHasOverlappingRendering="false"
            app:itemBackground="@drawable/back_selecter"
            app:itemIconTint="@drawable/icon_selecter"
            app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
            app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu"
            app:shapeAppearanceOverlay="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppTheme.BottomNavigationView" />

       </RelativeLayout>
       </layout>
```

[image: Here how it looks in xml preview]
[image: This is how it looks after installation]

Menu

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:ignore="MenuTitle">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_favorites"
        android:orderInCategory="1"
        android:title=""
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_tab_note"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        tools:ignore="AlwaysShowAction" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/abc"
        android:title=""
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:enabled="false"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:checkable="false"/>
    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_schedules"
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:title=""
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_tab_jobs"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/aa"
        android:title=""
        android:orderInCategory="2"
        android:enabled="false"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        android:checkable="false"/>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_music"
        android:title=""
        android:orderInCategory="3"
        android:icon="@drawable/setting"
        app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

Item icon selecter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true" android:color="@color/white" />
    <item android:color="#292D32"  />
</selector>
```

Item background selecter

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_checked="true">
        <layer-list>
            <item android:gravity="center">
                <shape android:shape="oval">
                    <solid android:width="3dp" android:color="#0F2B3D" />
                    <size android:width="@dimen/_40sdp" android:height="@dimen/_40sdp" />
                </shape>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```