# How do i get rid of this purple frame on icon on BottomNavigationBar

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm doing my first app in Android Studio using java and can't get rid of a purple heighlight on a selected item in bottomNavigationBar. Is there any solution to get rid of it?
[bottomNavigationBar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPX4g.png)

I was adding different attributes and none of them works

Main activity:

```
  <com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
        android:id="@+id/bottomNavigationView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/tab_view_bg"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        app:itemBackground="@android:color/transparent"
        app:itemIconSize="30dp"
        app:itemIconTint="@color/icons_colors"
        app:itemRippleColor="@android:color/transparent"
        app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav_menu" />
```

Menu for the navigation bar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/home"
        android:id="@+id/atlas" />
    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/fish"
        android:id="@+id/blank"/>
</menu>
```

Comment: just let me know which theme is set in your themes file under res folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I had the same problem as u can see [..HERE..](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77528532/bottom-navigation-bar-issue-in-android-kotolin). And I found an easy fix for this.

You Only need to change the theme of your project and then it will be gone.
Check this in your current project under `res\values\themes` and set the below theme.

```
<resources>
    <!-- MyApplication is your application. you only need to change the parent theme -->
    <style name="Base.Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

Then it will be solved. I hope this helps.