# How to Disable or Customize Shadow Effect in Material Design Components for Android Studio

Tags: android, bottomnavigationview, material-components-android, android-bottomnav, android-bottomnavigationview

I'm developing an Android app using Android Studio, and I'm using Material Design components, specifically `BottomNavigationView`. I want to disable or customize the shadow effect on this `BottomNavigationView`. I've tried setting `android:elevation="0dp"` directly in the layout XML file, but the shadow effect still persists. How can I properly disable or adjust the shadow effect on Material Design components like `BottomNavigationView`?[picture of the effect that I dont want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yY19G.png)

Here's the layout XML code I've tried:

```
<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/footer_menu"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    app:itemIconTint="@color/selector_footer"
    app:labelVisibilityMode="unlabeled"
    android:background="@color/white"
    app:menu="@menu/footer_menu"
    app:itemIconSize="32dp"/>
```

And this is the content of `selector_footer.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:color="@color/color_button"
        android:state_checked="true"/>

    <item android:color="@color/color_button_before_pressed"
        android:state_checked="false"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 0):

So I had the same problem as u can see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77528532/bottom-navigation-bar-issue-in-android-kotolin). And I found an easy fix for this.

You Only need to change the theme of your project and then it will be gone. Check this in your current project under `res\values\themes` and set the below theme.

```
<resources>
    <!-- MyApplication is your application. you only need to change the parent theme -->
    <style name="Base.Theme.MyApplication" parent="Theme.MaterialComponents.DayNight.NoActionBar">
```

**Then it will be solved. Just change the parent part.**

I hope this helps.